# Не работает transition при переходе: white-space: nowrap -> white-space: normal

Tags: css, веб-программирование, анимация, transition

```css
table{ 
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    background: #FFF; 
    height: 55px;
    max-width: 200px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap; 
} 
.tdsp{
    overflow: hidden;
}
table td>div { position: relative; }
table td>div div {  
    background: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: -11px;
}
table td>div div:hover{
    white-space: normal;
    z-index: 1;
}
th{      
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="bordered centered">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Тест</th>
 <th>Тест</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
<td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
<td><div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
<td><div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
<td><div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
<td><div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
<td><div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
<td><div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
<td><div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
<td><div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></div></td>
    </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
```

Не получается сделать плавную анимацию посредством transition. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы блоки текста не вылезали настолько резко. 
P.S. Является ли дурным тоном использование отрицательного margin в данном примере? (Использую т.к. абсолютное позиционирование создает отступ)

**P.S.** И все-таки один вопрос остался. Можно ли сохранить и троеточие, и плавный переход?

Comment: Переход и не должен быть плавным, насколько я знаю. Не то свойство, чтобы его анимировать. Сейчас Chrome даже анимацию с градиентами не поддерживает, что уж тут говорить.

Comment: @smellyshovel, спасибо за ответ. В таком случае, у меня вопрос: как сделать раскрытие при клике? Если вместо hover использовать active, то надо держать ЛКМ зажатой, в противном случае происходит схлопывание.

Comment: располагать текст изначально в несколько строк, но ограничивать максимальную высоту блока одной строкой (`max-height: 24px`) вместе с `overflow: hidden`, а при ховере допускать максимальную высоту на несколько строк - `max-height: 96px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `white-space` нет плавного перехода в CSS transitions. Но вы можете анимировать высоту блока - вот так:

```
table td > div div {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 24px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s, z-index 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}

table td > div div:hover {
  max-height: 96px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s, z-index 0s;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Этим кодом мы:

1. Всегда располагаем текст в несколько строк (да, от многоточия в конце придется отказаться);
2. Но ограничиваем максимальную высоту блока одной строкой;
3. А при ховере допускаем максимальную высоту в несколько строк (подберите значение экспериментально, не задавайте слишком большое, иначе анимация будет резкая);
4. `z-index` важно анимировать так, как в примере, иначе при сворачивании надписи со следующих строк будут проступать поверх той, на которой был ховер, и которая еще не свернулась.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 55px;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.tdsp {
  overflow: hidden;
}
table td > div {
  position: relative;
}
table td > div div {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: -11px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s, z-index 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}

table td > div div:hover {
  max-height: 96px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s, z-index 0s;
  z-index: 1;
}

th {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table class="bordered centered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Тест</th>
      <th>Тест</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

[Или посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/ryd7xjk8/)

Comment: Все отлично, спасибо!